# uninitialized constant Squeel

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try and deploy our application using capistrano I get the error listed above. No errors when using squeel on our development machines which are macs our app server has the following specs
Rails 3.0.10
Ruby 1.9.2p290
postgres 8.2.4
Redhat 5.7

It seems to throw the error when doing a rake db:migrate in the deployment process

Our Macs are running OSX 10.7.2
Rails 3.0.10
Ruby 1.9.2p290
sqlite 3.7.7.1

Comment: Come on man, post a stack trace. We're not psychics. If we were we'd guess you're trying to use [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) but are dyslexic.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a Gemfile issue.  The squeel gem was only loading in the dev and test environments, once it was moved out of the test and development block in the gemfile it worked fine in production